# MS Graph lastModifiedDateTime and SharePoint REST API TimeLastModified are different for the same file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-rest-api

I uploaded a file to a user's OneDrive using the Web Interface and then I fetched the file information using two APIs: MS Graph API and SharePoint REST API.

For **MS Graph API** I used the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b{drive-id}/items/{item-id}
```

and the respose I got:

```
{
    ***
    "createdDateTime": "2019-12-09T15:03:52Z",
    "eTag": "\"{9E8670D4-185F-4E8D-B2E5-61819E769BC3},2\"",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-12-09T15:04:12Z",
    "name": "test.psd",
    "cTag": "\"c:{9E8670D4-185F-4E8D-B2E5-61819E769BC3},2\"",
    "size": 56783858,

    "lastModifiedBy": {
        "user": {
            "email": "batman@keepitdev02.onmicrosoft.com",
            "id": "6e14d588-63db-46e4-b70d-0f00050dafa4",
            "displayName": "Batman"
        }
    },
    "fileSystemInfo": {
        "createdDateTime": "2019-12-09T15:03:52Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-12-09T15:04:12Z"
    },
    ***
}
```

For the **SharePoint REST API** I used the endpoint:

```
https://*my.sharepoint.com/personal/*/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='*/test.psd')
```

The response I got:

---

```
        "LinkingUrl": "",
        "MajorVersion": 1,
        "MinorVersion": 0,
        "Name": "test.psd",
        "ServerRelativeUrl": "/*/test.psd",
        "TimeCreated": "2019-12-09T15:03:52Z",
        "TimeLastModified": "2019-12-09T15:04:11Z",
        "Title": null,
        "UIVersion": 512,
        "UIVersionLabel": "1.0",
        "UniqueId": *
}
```

---

The *modification time* that APIs returned are:

- MS Graph: 2019-12-09T15:04:**12Z**
- SharePoint REST API: 2019-12-09T15:04:**11Z**

  As you can see they are different by 1 second. Can someone explain why do I see such a difference?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that FileSystemInfo is imported from the file metadata, while the lastModified on the DriveItem is Graph info.

The one second lag may be the space between the request and response which occurs in relation to the differences referenced above.

If it's an issue I would only select one or the other.